# Facing unity problems after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, upgrade, nvidia, monitor

I upgraded to 12.04 and had problems with unity.

So this is what I did >>

1) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Export DISPLAY=:0

ccsm
```

2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

3) Enabled `unityplugin`

4)  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
unity --replace
```

it worked with a couple of error messages

now I have to put in start up application

```
export DISPLAY=:0
unity --replace
```

NVIDIA software recognizes my monitor but Ubuntu sees it as laptop.
Something isn't right. Can someone point out what info I need to put here for people to help.  I have been upgrading this from 8 ish so have altered lots especially when compiz fusion first came out.

Also if I run recovery session and type `unity --replace` it starts and runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Comment: makes no change to the `unity --replace` still brings up errors and for some reason on startup applications it works but if I do it in session it crashes unity with errors.